# For loop within itemize + arrays of strings

Tags: loops, strings

Consider a document in which there are a few sections containing lists.  The content is predictable; the list is preceded by a tiny preamble.  Something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}%

% BASIC QUALIFICATIONS

\def\qualificationa{A degree}%
\def\qualificationb{Skill}%
\def\qualificationc{Common sense}%
%\def\qualificationd{Enthusiasm}%

\begin{document}

% duties
\section*{Basic Qualifications}

The successful candidate will have the following basic qualifications:

\begin{itemize}
\item{\qualificationa}%
\item{\qualificationb}%
\item{\qualificationc}%
%\item{\qualificationd}%
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

This mwe is inefficient and kind of useless for obvious reasons: (1) the use of definitions does not reduce the size or complexity of the code (2) one has to manage the `a`, `b`, *etc.* suffixes.

The following pseudocode would address both of these points

```
\documentclass{article}%

% BASIC QUALIFICATIONS

% define an array called \qualifications which has the elements:
% A degree
% Skill
% Common sense
% Enthusiasm

\begin{document}

% duties
\section*{Basic Qualifications}

The successful candidate will have the following basic qualifications:

\begin{itemize}
% for all elements in the array, wrap the value of the array element at index defined by the for loop counter with `\item{` and `}`
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such list processing capabilities are provided by [`etoolbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

% BASIC QUALIFICATIONS
\listadd\qualifications{A degree}%
\listadd\qualifications{Skill}%
\listadd\qualifications{Common sense}%
\listadd\qualifications{Enthusiasm}%

\begin{document}

% duties
\section*{Basic Qualifications}

The successful candidate will have the following basic qualifications:

\begin{itemize}
  \forlistloop{\item}{\qualifications}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Grateful for this suggestion.  This solution solves each of the issues identified in the original question.